# ArcGIS Enterprise 10.8.1: Trying to create feature layer with referenced data in Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I am trying to write a script that creates feature layers in ArcGIS Enterprise based on layers in an ArcGIS Pro Project. I do not want to copy the data to the server, only reference it. The data comes out of a SDE database that is also registered with the respective ArcGIS Server.

While doing the process manually works well (right-click layer --> Share as Weblayer --> Reference registered data), if I try to do the same with Python, I always end up with a hosted feature layer, which means that the data has been copied to the server instead of referencing it.

This is the code I use. Am I missing something?

```
            featDraft = Map.getWebLayerSharingDraft("HOSTING_SERVER", "FEATURE", "REF_" + service6, layer)
            featDraft.copyDataToServer = "False"
            featDraft.description = metadata_description
            featDraft.allowExporting="True"
            featDraft.overwriteExistingService="True"
            featDraft.portalFolder="REF_" + Mapname
            featDraft.tags=Tags
            mapDoc.save()
            featDraft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_output_filename)

            # Stage Service
            sd_filename = service6 + ".sd"
            sd_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sd_filename)
            arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft_output_filename, sd_output_filename, 5)

            # Share to portal
            print("Uploading Service Definition...")
            arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_output_filename, "My Hosted Services")
```

Follow up:
Putting a arcpy.GetMessages(1) into my code gives me the following error:

```
WARNING 000710: Unable to connect to the server
```

I assume that this means that the script is not able to access the database where the data resides to reference it. However, I am not sure where to put this information. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using ArcPy or the ArcGIS API for Python ?

Comment: This is arcpy, but I am open for solutions based on the ArcGIS API, too.

Comment: Look at the 2nd code example here for StageService and do the GetMessages and see if you're getting any warnings, like "data is not registered and will be copied".  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/server/stage-service.htm

Comment: @KHibma : Thanks for the tip. I did as you suggested and get a warning, which I am not sure how to interprete correctly. I have adjusted my question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem: One has to create a `MapImageSharingDraft` instead of a `FeatureSharingDraft`. In a second step, one has to edit the created SDDraft-file (XML) to allow feature access. As a result, two services are being created (one Map Image Service and one Feature Service). Please check the second code sample from the following page (Modify SDDraft example). It includes a code block on how to edit the SDDraft-file: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/sharing/mapimagesharingdraft-class.htm